# html input files binding with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, knockout.js

I have a viewModel named **MainViewModel**.

```
var MainViewModel = function(){
    this.selectedFiles = ko.observableArray();

    this.onFileSelectedEvent = function(evt){

    }
}
```

and I have an HTML page that includes input that type is file.

```
<input type="file" data-bind="event:{ change: onFileSelectedEvent }"/>
```

I want to fill **selectedFiles** with **onFileSelectedEvent** handler. But **onFileSelectedEvent** parameter is coming type of **MainViewModel** it does not include selected files.

How can I handle selected files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your [`event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) handler by default **the second parameter** is the event object:

```
var MainViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.selectedFiles = ko.observableArray();

    self.onFileSelectedEvent = function(vm, evt){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(evt.target.files,  function(file) {
            self.selectedFiles.push(file.name);
        });
    }
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBwTZ/).

The first parameter is the current data context so in your case the `MainViewModel`